# Form1.cs [Design] is gone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

for whatever reason my `Form1.cs [Design]` File is not appearing when creating an new `Windows Forms Application`. I do not really know what the Problem is. How to fix that?

Comment: Try pressing SHIFT+F7 on the code view to switch to design mode.

Comment: @Josh dont works

Comment: Pick the correct project template to get started.  .NET Framework, not .NET Core.

Comment: There is an error in your Design class `Form1.Designer.cs` .Open this file remove the  error

Comment: @ApolloDev:    It would be better if you add some screenshots of the errors you come across.